# Test React stateless private function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react component is like this i am rendering part of component using getMenuItems method.

```
const TransactionListFilter = (props) => {
  const getMenuItems = () => filterCriteriaItems.map((data) =>
    <MenuItem value={data.valu} name={data.name} >{data.name}</MenuItem>,
  );
  return (
        <Dropdown
          className="Transaction-List-Filter-container-dropdown"
          selectMode="single"
          defaultText="See All"
          onMenuItemClick={handleFilterChange}
        >
          <Menu>
            {
              getMenuItems()
            }
          </Menu>
        </Dropdown>
  );
};
```

How i can test method getMenuItems any Idea?

Comment: The way you did it is making `getMenuItems` function tightly coupled to `TransactionListFilter`, so there is no way for you to test `getMenuItems` in isolation without having to use `TransactionListFilter`. Consider passing this function from props for decoupling. Where is `filterCriteriaItems` coming from? It looks like a global array. If so you can create a duplicate of this function just for your tests but I don't encourage that.

Comment: Can you test a function within another function? Same is here. Just test a Component

Comment: may i know reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are hiding the method `getMenuItems` to be an internal working of the `TransactionListFilter` function. Are you sure you want to test it? As soon as you refactor the `TransactionListFilter` method, your test will break. As far as I see, you have 2 options:

Refactor to a class:

```
class TransactionListFilter {
    getMenuItems(){
        return filterCriteriaItems.map((data) =>
            <MenuItem value={data.valu} name={data.name}>{data.name}</MenuItem>,
    );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Dropdown
        className="Transaction-List-Filter-container-dropdown"
        selectMode="single"
        defaultText="See All"
        onMenuItemClick={handleFilterChange}
            >
            <Menu>
            {
                this.getMenuItems()
    }
    </Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    );
    }
};
```

Hacky translation of the function (e.g. converting the function to a string, then parsing the string up until the return, and passing the result to the `Function` constructor). That would look something like this: (at your own risk)

```
const getMenuItems = new Function('', `${TransactionListFilter.toString().match(/\getMenuItems.*=.*=>(.*)\)/s)[1]};`)
```